# How to process json object in highchart

Tags: ajax, json, highcharts

I receive an array json object. And now I don't know how I can process it in javascript code to series section data.  I use this example of highchart `column-rotated-labels`. In this object has two columns `AVG` and other `title`, and length of this object might 20.
This is my codes:

```
    $('#showresult').click(function() {
$.ajax({
               url : "../../coursestatus",
               type : "get",
                data : {
                     major : $('#get').val(),
                     year : $('#yearlist').val(),
                     semester : $('#semester').val()
                 },
                 success : function(data) {
                         alert(data.length);
                           $(function () {
                                  $('#container').highcharts({
                                             chart: {  type: 'column'
                                                           },
                                             title: { text: 'World\'s largest cities per 2014' },

                                             xAxis: {
                                                     type: 'category',
                                                         labels: {
                                                          rotation: -45,
                                                       }
                                                      },
                                             yAxis: {  min: 0,
                                              title: {
                                                      text: 'Population (millions)'
                                                  } },
                                             legend: {  enabled: false },
                      tooltip: { pointFormat: 'Population in 2008: <b>{point.y:.1f} millions</b>'  },
                              series: [{ // I don't know how I can process data object to set that's elements to this
                                              name: 'Population',  
                                                  data: [
                                                     JSON.parse("[" + data + "]") 
                                                                    ],
                                                      dataLabels: {  enabled: true,
                                                                        rotation: -90,
                                                                        color: '#FFFFFF',
                                                                        align: 'right',
                                                                        x: 4,
                                                                        y: 10,
                                                            style: { fontSize: '13px',
                                                                      fontFamily: 'Verdana, sans-serif', textShadow: '0 0 3px black'
                                                                        }
                                                                    }
                                                                }]
                                                            });
                                                        });
```

And this object include this elements:

[image]

`title` columns includes course name and `avg` columns includes mark for that course.
And this is data is in data object:

```
[{"title":"Math","avg":20},{"title":"Network","avg":18},{"title":"Operating system","avg":16}]
```

And above data is has 3 length and it is simple, in fact this object maybe that's length is >10.
Thank u!

Comment: Without knowing what data looks like, it's hard to help. Please post the contents of the data variable using console.log(data). Is it being returned as a string or a json object ?

Comment: Your data array is completely invalid (incorrect structure, missing commas etc), so please paste your data.

Answer (score 0):

I founded similar problem in this page and I solved my problem. 
[Populate Highcharts with JSON data using jQuery](http://karanbalkar.com/2014/06/populate-highcharts-with-json-data-using-jquery/)